# How does the function get_and_convert_block_blob_from_height work?

Tags: lmdb, blockchain-import, blockchain-export

"get_and_convert_block_blob_from_height" function is called multiple times when running the binaries such as depth, export, import. What does it do and how does it work ?

Comment: What code base are you looking in? There's no function named "get_and_convert_block_blob_from_height" in Monero.

Comment: If you're actually referring to `get_block_blob_from_height`, that is simply fetching the block data from the database.